# Python/Scrapy not recognizing file changes

Tags: python, scrapy

This question might be a little bit hard to understand but I'll try my best.

I have a Scrapy project. I am editing spiders, but when I make a change, Scrapy doesn't recognize that I have saved the file/made changes.

Another example: I have completely deleted all traces of pipelines.py to test if this was happening, and Scrapy still thinks it's there.

I am issuing,

```
scrapy crawl penguin
```

if it matters. Nothing special. I have tried different log levels, stuff like that. Still doesn't pick up my changes.

I have looked for some hidden caches but haven't found anything. I'm not a Python guy by any means but this is bizarre.

Yes I am sure I am in the correct directory and the files are saving.

Python 2.7.5, Mavericks 10.9

Comment: Have you tried deleting all your *.pyc files?

Comment: @pault. I have. In fact I don't even have any .pyc files left to delete.

Comment: More info please! OS, Scrapy version and output errors etc...